# Integrability regarding a probability density

Tags: probability, measure-theory, expectation

Given a probability density

$$f_Y= \frac{1}{(y+1)^2}*1_{[0,\infty)}$$
Where 1 is indicator function

Is the Random variable $Y$ integrable? In other word, is $E[Y]<\infty$.

I am confused by, if I perform the integral from 0 to infinity, the integral becomes infinite. However, the probability is 0 for $Y->\infty$. Therefore the $Y$ cannot attain infinity as value, and if density cannot attain infinity and $Y$ also not, the expectation should be bounded. How can I calculate $E[Y]$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are totally right, $$E[Y] = \int_0^\infty \frac{y}{(y+1)^2} dy = +\infty$$
And yes, $Y$ is finite almost surely. But there is no reason why the expectation should be bounded!

It's true that **if** the expectation is bounded **then** the random variable is finite almost surely. But it's not true the other way around… Y above is an example for it.

Comment: Another classic example: Consider a random variable, $Z$, with probability mass function $\mathsf P(Z{=}2^n)=2^{-n}\cdotp\mathbf 1_{n\in\Bbb N^+}~$ . This $Z$ is almost surely finite (as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathsf P(Z=2^n)=0$), but the expected value clearly does not converge. $~~\mathsf E(Z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n2^{-n}$ .